# Verify construction of cube using vanishing point perspective

Tags: projective-geometry

Suppose we are a creative individual, and during our math exam would like to draw a picture of a cube using the vanishing point perspective. Let $A$ and $B$ be two adjacent vertices of a square in the plane, and $V$ the vanishing point. We extend segments from each vertex of the square to $V$.

The question is how far along each segment should we place the remaining vertices of the cube. Let $E$ be the remaining vertex lying on the segment $\overline{BV}$:

[image]
[image]

> Proposition: $E$ is the intersection of the bisector of $\angle VAB$ and the segment $\overline{BV}$, so that $\angle VAE=\angle EAB$.

Proof: In the plane, the bisectors of opposite vertices of any square should be equal. If this fact holds in any *projected square*, this gives a unique solution and we are done.

[image]

Can anyone provide a proof for this claim?

Comment: Which claim would you like help with? And what thoughts of your own do have about the problem?

Comment: No, this doesn't hold for the projected square. And if I am right, this problem is indeterminate, as this depends on the focal length, which is free.

Comment: @RobArthan I need help to prove the highlighted conjecture that my construction of the point $E$ is correct

Comment: @M.Nestor: so make that clear in your question! Don't write "Proposition ..." when you mean "I think ... holds and that would solve the problem (but I don't know how to prove it)".

Comment: Hi Rob, I added the proof verification tag, since I need verification for my proof of the proposition

Comment: Your question is not phrased as a proof verification question. The only question you have asked is "Can anyone provide a proof of this claim".

Comment: As @Yves Daoust has said, this problem is indeterminate. Thus, you have found "a" solution (more or less pleasing to the eye), but you cannot claim that this is "the" solution... A clue : to give unique solutions you need to have 3 points on a same straight line (L), then you can work on the placement of a fourth point on (L) using the so-called "cross-ratio", which is an indispensable tool for doing "projective geometry".